# Returning a map of string and different vector datatypes in C++

Tags: c++, vector

I know questions like this has been asked before, but I am still struggling to find an answer.

I am trying to return a method of `map` of `string` and `vector`; I have two vectors `std::vector<Eigen::MatrixXd> samples` and `std::vector<std::string> sample_names`

This is what I have done so far:

```
std::map<std::string, std::vector> FileReader::get_data() {
    std::map<std::string, std::vector> content;

    std::vector<Eigen::MatrixXd> samples;
    std::vector<std::string> sample_names;

    for (auto i : list_dir()) {
        if (contains_number(i)) {
            samples.push_back(load_csv(location + "/" + i));
            sample_names.push_back(i);
        }
    }

    content["samples"] = samples;
    content["sample_names"] = sample_names;

    return content;
}
```

Obviously, I am getting an error of

```
error: type/value mismatch at argument 2 in template parameter list for 'template<class _Key, class _Tp, class _Compare, class _Alloc> class std::map'
         std::map<std::string, std::vector> get_data(void);
```

Because I don't have a datatype for `vector` in the method. If I add `string` or `Eigen::MatrixXd` they both cannot go hand-in-hand. I know that I could use `boost::any` but it would be an extra library which needs to be compiled (?), and C++ is not dynamically typed.

Is there any way I could do this by not have an extra library?

**Update-1:**

Another way I think I could do is that in the constructor have a private variable of `vector<Eigen::MatriXd> samples` & `vector<std::string> smaple_names` and create two methods of same vector types `get_samples()` and `get_sample_names()` then use something like `this->samples = samples` and `this->sample_name`. Is this the only other way?

**Update-2:**

It looks like `std::any` is in C++17 - http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/any. If `any`one :p interested.

**Update-3:**

> If anyone is looking for the answer it's at
>
> https://stackoverflow.com/a/44896365/3782963

Comment: "Is there any way I could do this by not have an extra library?" You could write `std::any` yourself... :P I don't think it is possible without it though. You might want to rethink your design.

Comment: @Rakete1111 Can you see my update?

Comment: @Rakete1111 How would I write that :|

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree that `std::any` (or `boost::any`) is a bit overkill for this situation. `std::variant` (or `boost::variant`) would be a better choice here, because you know exactly what 2 types you want to store.

If you don't want to use any additional libraries like Boost and don't have access to C++17, you can try to emulate `std::variant` yourself in a dummy implementation (if you can't/don't want to write a full one). Something like:

```
struct data {
    // constructors...

    std::vector<Eigen::MatrixXd> samples;
    std::vector<std::string> names;
    int index = -1;
};
```

Then you can store your data in a `std::map<std::string, data>`:

```
std::map<std::string, data> content;
content.emplace(std::make_pair("samples", data{samples, 0}));
content.emplace(std::make_pair("sample_names", data{sample_names, 1}));
```

Then you just need to check the index to know which `std::vector` you have to use.

Comment: The idea of using a struct is a good one, but then why return a map with two of them? You could just return the struct directly and fill both members in (and scrap the `index` member).

Comment: @ArthurTacca Well the map is needed because I think OP wants to access them with a string key. If that would not be needed, a `std::pair` would have also worked.

Comment: I am going to try this tomorrow and let you know. +1 for help

Comment: @Rakete1111 So I created an object of `std::map<std::string, data> get_data1()` and used `content.emplace()` to add to the data. Now I don't understand how I would use it. Is it something like `get_data1()["samples"]`? I get an error if I do that.

Comment: @akshay Nope, you need to check the index. So `auto data = get_data1(); if (data.index == 0) /*use samples*/; if (data.index == 1) /*use names*/;` That's why you need an index, to know which of the 2 vectors you are using in any given `data` type.

Comment: @Rakete1111 Why do I get `error: 'class std::map<std::basic_string<char>, Spikes::FileReader::data>' has no member named 'index'
     std::cout<< data.index;`? I kept the `struct` content in the public part of the constructor.

Comment: @akshay Oh yeah, sorry. `get_data1()["samples"].samples` and `get_data1()["sample_names"].names`. You can use the index if you are not sure.

Comment: @Rakete1111 Now I'm getting this error `error: no matching function for call to 'Spikes::FileReader::data::data(<brace-enclosed initializer list>)'
     content.emplace(std::make_pair("samples", data{samples, 0}));` :|

Comment: @akshay It works fine for me. Try to find it out yourself. If you are stuck and didn't find the solution online, you could ask a new question.

Comment: @akshay I haven't tested, but I think you need to replace the two `data{...}` expressions with `data{samples, {}, 0}` and `data{{}, sample_names, 1}`. The index is the third item in the struct, so needs to be third in the initialiser list.

Comment: Ah I see the problem. Where Rakete1111 has written "`// constructors...`", he has manually written two overloaded constructors. You can miss that out, but then you need to change the way you construct the `data` objects in the way I said.

Comment: Thanks, @ArthurTacca. This approach of actually helped me.

Answer (score 1):

Why use a map at all? You could use `std::pair<std::vector<std::string>, std::vector<Eigen::MatrixXd>>` instead.

Here is what the function would look like:

```
std::pair<std::vector<std::string>, std::vector<Eigen::MatrixXd>> FileReader::get_data() 
{
    std::vector<Eigen::MatrixXd> samples;
    std::vector<std::string> sample_names;

    for (auto i : list_dir()) {
        if (contains_number(i)) {
            samples.push_back(load_csv(location + "/" + i));
            sample_names.push_back(i);
        }
    }

    return std::make_pair(sample_names, samples);
}
```

If you're using C++11, you can replace the return statement with just

```
return {sample_names, samples};
```

Comment: And how would you return the content?

Comment: I actually wanted to do with key-pair if I couldn't do that I'll try this. +1 for help